# How to run Angular code from Github in Vscode

Tags: angular, github, visual-studio-code

Can anyone please help me on running someone's code that I downloaded from Github in Visual Studio code

Comment: You can directly run `github project` online without downloaded it.

Comment: Could you pls explain how it works? I am new to Git

Comment: Please check given answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can directly run Angular GitHub projects without downloading on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/). Just replace the GitHub URL with the Stackblitz URL. Replace https://github.com/ with https://stackblitz.com/github/.

Example:

- GitHub URL: https://github.com/onecompileman/angular-stateside
- replace with: https://stackblitz.com/github/onecompileman/angular-stateside

Or run an Angular project downloaded from GitHub on your computer.

Note: You must have NodeJS and angular-cli installed on your computer.

Go into your downloaded folder, open a command prompt and run `npm install`. After it completes, run `ng serve --open` and your project will automatically open in your browser.

Answer (score 8):

Try it

1. Open VS code with corresponding downloaded folder
2. In VS code open Integrated command prompt/terminal
3. run `npm install` command
4. run `ng serve` command

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the angular project
2. Unzip the project. Suppose, your angular project name is `my-app`.
3. After Unzip, open the project folder.
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Right click</kbd> on background
5. You will see `Open Powershel/Open Window Here` on the popup Menu
6. Write the command: `npm install` or `npm i`
7. After installing npm, write the command: `ng serve` or `ng serve -open` or `ng serve -o`
8. Done!

Answer (score 0):

## Clone the repository from Github - Blank preferred

Open Visual code

## Run commands

ng new notepad

npm install -g @angular/cli in the Visual Code

cd notepad

ng serve --open

## Adding a remote repository

git remote add origin https://github.com/OWNER/notepad.git

git remote -v

## View existing remotes

> origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)

> origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (push)

### Development server

Run `ng serve` for a dev server. Navigate to `http://localhost:4200/`. The application will automatically reload if you change any of the source files.

Answer (score -1):

If it shows an error as

> Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"

Apply command

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

to fix it.